# Oracle SQL Outer Left Join not returning rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to map 3 tables in oracle database:

```
testHdr, testDet, testOther
```

testHdr is the header table, testDet is the detail table, and testOther is just the supplementary table that i need to get few columns from.

It is possible that there are data in testHdr but not in testDet. I want to show either empty/null value from testDet if there is no value.

Key to map testHdr to testDet is adj_no and adj_no2

```
SELECT hdr.*, det.*, othr.*  
FROM testHdr hdr, testDet det, testOther othr
where hdr.adj_no = det.adj_no (+)
and hdr.adj_no2 = det.adj_no2 (+)
and i.key3 = det.key3 
and hdr.adj_no = '112'
```

*112 has only header record but no detail record

- I wish to get data for hdr.adj_no = 112, if there are header data like 113, 114, etc, it won't show in the query result.

I tried the above query with outer leftjoin but it shows:

```
ORA-01416: two tables cannot be outer-joined to each other
```

Comment: Move the adj_no condition where to left join condition

Comment: @AbhilashRVankayala
do you mean `where hdr.adj_no (+) = det.adj_no 
and hdr.adj_no2 = det.adj_no2 (+)`?

Comment: No, I suggested the way Tim has posted in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an explicit left join:

```
SELECT hdr.*, det.*, othr.*  
FROM testHdr hdr
LEFT JOIN testDet det
    ON hdr.adj_no = det.adj_no AND
       hdr.adj_no2 = det.adj_no2
LEFT JOIN testOther othr
--  ON <some condition>
WHERE i.key3 = det.key3 AND
      hdr.adj_no = '112'
```

In your original query you never specified any join conditions for the `testOther` table, which means you are doing a cross join of that table.  While this should not affect your actual problem, if the cross join were not intended, you should add an `ON` clause restricting this join.

One reason why most of the database world has moved away from the implicit join syntax you used is precisely because it makes it hard to see what is being joined, and it also makes it easier to miss a join condition.

Comment: Hi tim, thanks for the help, sorry i think i didn't mentioned it clearly, the results i wish to get is hdr.adj_no = 112, means if in header table there are 113, 114, it wont return that value. I will update my question.

Comment: @hades I stand by my answer.  If you want to handle missing values then you can use `COALESCE` on the column which might have `NULL` values.